# RandomRangeInt is not allowed to be called from a MonoBehavior constructor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, random

I'm trying to genereate a random number by using th the UnityEngine.Random.Range(min, max) function, but I'm getting the following error:

> RandomRangeInt is not allowed to be called from a MonoBehaviour constructor (or instance field initializer), call it in Awake or Start instead. Called from MonoBehaviour 'myClass' on game object 'GameObject'.
>   See "Script Serialization" page in the Unity Manual for further details.
>   UnityEngine.Random:Range(Int32, Int32)

And the following code (a simplified version from the one I'm using):

```
public class myClass : MonoBehavior {
    // Some instance variables
    List<Property> listA;
    int value;

   // Constructor
    public myClass(){
        init();
        search();
    }

    public void init(){
        // Some instructions
    }

    public void search(){
        int randomNumber = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 10); // Error!
    }
}
```

I've been searching on the Internet about this error, but I couldn't find any clear solution. For example:

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1039914/argumentexception-randomrangeint-can-only-be-calle-1.html (but it isn't a static variable)

https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/random-range-variable-problem.93054/ (but I need the random number after calling Awake)

Comment: You shouldnt use a constructor for `MonoBehaviour` classes. For code executing at the start, you should write it in a `void Start ()` or `void Awake()`.

Comment: That exception description is pretty self-explanatory, use `Start()` or `Awake()` instead of the constructor.

Comment: Thank you!! I put the content of `myClass()` constructor in `Start()` (`Awake()` is also ok) and it worked perfectly!